# Run Auto Incremental MySQL Query on WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

The situation is I moved a ton of single WordPress sites over to WordPress Multisite. I need to make a quick fix to the paths of the images I migrated over. I mistakenly have /sites/#/sites/#/ twice in my image urls, but it only needs to be once like this /sites/#/

So What I would like to do is run a mysql query one time to fix this issue, then I plan to remove the code below from the server since its a NO NO to leave online.

The code I have below is suppose to auto increment the site # for me, but for some reason can't get it to work. Any input on how I can make this script run and do the task would be very appreciated.

Thanks

```
<?php

require_once("wp-config.php");

global $wpdb;

for($n=0; $n<=8; $n++): 

$wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_$n_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, '/sites/$n/sites/$n/', '/sites/$n/')");

endfor; 

?>
```

EDITED: I answered my own question below...

Comment: A start would be to use `for($n=0; $n<=8; $n++):` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and still wont work.

Comment: And what does that mean "still won't work"? Which result do you exprect, which do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it!

```
<?php

/* Run MySQL Query to fix invalid image url paths
 * August 09, 2014
 **/

echo "Starting....<br />";
require_once("wp-config.php");

global $wpdb;

/* Change 1 to the # of the starting site
 * Change 100 to the # of the ending site
 **/
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++):
echo "Site $i: Start...";

$wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_{$i}_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, '/sites/$i/sites/$i/', '/sites/$i/')");

echo "Finished.<br />";

endfor;

echo "All done.<br />";

?>
```